# Converting one numeric type to another by using type.parse(var) in c#

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion

I'm new to c# and I've just encountered some problem with converting. I created 2 variables of different **numeric** types, just like that:

```
using System;
namespace Exercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int biggerType = 5;
            short smallerType = short.Parse(biggerType);

            Console.WriteLine(smallerType);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to convert this int variable to short variable by using `short.Parse(biggerType)` but the program would not compile as it displays an error: **cannot covert from 'int' to 'string'**.

Later I tried another way of converting, and I wrote this:

```
using System;
namespace Exercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int biggerType = 5;
            short smallerType = Convert.ToInt16(biggerType);

            Console.WriteLine(smallerType);
        }
    }
}
```

This time, though, everything worked just fine. However, it suprised me as I got to know that `Convert.ToInt16(biggerType)` kind of references to short.Parse().

So my question is, why is that happening?

Comment: `Parse` supports string inputs and you supply an `int`, which is the mismatch the error is pointing out. `ToInt16` on the other hand does accept `int`, so that piece of code works

Answer (score 1):

> However, it surprised me as I got to know that Convert.ToInt16(biggerType) kind of references to short.Parse()

No, `Convert.ToInt16` only uses `short.Parse()` internally for the overload that accepts `string` (and `object` when a `string` is passed).

The purpose of `short.Parse()` is to *parse* a string representation of an integer into a .NET `short`.

What you are trying to do is *convert* between numeric data types, and because `short` cannot accommodate the range of values that `int` can, this must be done explicitly, and may cause an exception:

```
short smallerType = (short)biggerType;
```

And this is what happens internally when you call [`Convert.ToInt16(int)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,845).

---

If you were to convert a `short` to an `int`, this conversion can be implicit because it is guaranteed to succeed:

```
short smallerType = default;
int biggerType = smallerType; // Implicit conversion is fine here
```

A full list of explicit and implicit conversions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions).

Comment: I also normally use ```(short)biggerType``` but I was just curious why the way presented above is not right. Nevertheless, thanks for the answer